# Prevent docker from resolving domain names to local address

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have :

- a Jenkins instance inside a docker container
- a docker registry inside another docker container.

In order to be able to access them easily from the outside, I created 2 subdomains :

- `jenkins.acme.com`
- `registry.acme.com`

But they are physically on the same machine

At the end of a Jenkins job, I want to build an image and push it to the docker registry.

The problem is that, as `jenkins.acme.com` and `registry.acme.com` are the same machine, the subdomain is resolved locally : `127.0.1.1`, instead of `193.70.xxx.yyy`

As a result, jenkins will try to push the image on `127.0.1.1` in its own network which does not make sense.

So far, the only solution I find is to provide manually the host via :

```
docker run [...] add-host registry.acme.com:193.70.xxx.yyy
```

But I don't like to write the ip-address explicitly. Is there a way to tell docker to not resolve the domain name locally ?

Comment: registry.acme.com resolving to a local ip address is not a standard configuration. There is nothing to be done at docker config here, instead you should look at how your local network is configured. And if you don't want to deal with that, then add-host thing seems like a fine work-around.